# gtk4 rust example failing with "error[E0432]: unresolved import `gtk::FileDialog`"

Tags: rust

Testing the [gtk examples from the main branch](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/master/examples) some of them are building and working but `text_viewer` (`cargo run --bin text_viewer`) and some others are failing with the error below

```bash
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/tmp/gtk4-rs-master/examples$ cargo run --bin text_viewer
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
    Skipping git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir` due to update strategy in .gitmodules
    Skipping git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir-files` due to update strategy in .gitmodules
warning: private item shadows public glob re-export
   --> gdk4/src/lib.rs:85:1
    |
85  | mod functions;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: the name `functions` in the type namespace is supposed to be publicly re-exported here
   --> gdk4/src/lib.rs:110:9
    |
110 | pub use auto::*;
    |         ^^^^^^^
note: but the private item here shadows it
   --> gdk4/src/lib.rs:85:1
    |
85  | mod functions;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: `#[warn(hidden_glob_reexports)]` on by default

warning: `gdk4` (lib) generated 1 warning
warning: private item shadows public glob re-export
   --> gtk4/src/lib.rs:148:1
    |
148 | mod functions;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: the name `functions` in the type namespace is supposed to be publicly re-exported here
   --> gtk4/src/lib.rs:105:9
    |
105 | pub use auto::*;
    |         ^^^^^^^
note: but the private item here shadows it
   --> gtk4/src/lib.rs:148:1
    |
148 | mod functions;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: `#[warn(hidden_glob_reexports)]` on by default

warning: `gtk4` (lib) generated 1 warning
   Compiling gtk4-rs-examples v0.1.0 (/home/oz-mint/tmp/gtk4-rs-master/examples)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `gtk::FileDialog`
 --> examples/text_viewer/main.rs:7:71
  |
7 | use gtk::{gio, glib, Application, ApplicationWindow, Builder, Button, FileDialog, TextView};
  |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ no `FileDialog` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `gtk4-rs-examples` (bin "text_viewer") due to previous error
```

You can see another example from same folder is running like in [the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btbkQ.png).

system is linux mint 21.2
gtk is 4.6.6

and configued the cargo toml like below

```ini
[dependencies.gtk]
path = "../gtk4"
package = "gtk4"
features = ["v4_6"]
```

I followed the [gtk4-rs books hello world](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/git/book/hello_world.html) and saw that also working, meaning the gtk binding looks like it's working, I can create a button and click.

How can I fix `` error[E0432]: unresolved import `gtk::FileDialog`​ `` and see `text_viewer` working?

### Update after I learn that function exist in 4.10 only

Thanks @Cafce25 I tried to checkout the commit id and when I build I got the error below. What am I missing ?

```
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/tmp/gtk4-rs$ git checkout 06f5c84c936f046d17a9d5ddd00d64a70f20c056
Note: switching to '06f5c84c936f046d17a9d5ddd00d64a70f20c056'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 06f5c84c9 Put modules of examples in separate files (#330)
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/tmp/gtk4-rs$ cd examples/
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/tmp/gtk4-rs/examples$ code text_viewer/
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/tmp/gtk4-rs/examples$ cargo run --bin text_viewer
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs`
    Skipping git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir` due to update strategy in .gitmodules
    Skipping git submodule `https://github.com/gtk-rs/gir-files` due to update strategy in .gitmodules
error: no matching package named `cairo-rs` found
location searched: https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs
required by package `gtk4 v0.1.0 (/home/oz-mint/tmp/gtk4-rs/gtk4)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `v4_10` feature only widget as per the [documentation](https://docs.rs/gtk4/latest/gtk4/struct.FileDialog.html):

> ```
> #[repr(transparent)]
> pub struct FileDialog { /* private fields */ }
> ```
>
> Available on **crate feature v4_10** only.

so you'll have to update your version of gtk4 and adjust the `features` accordingly, or use the [examples written for your version of gtk](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/06f5c84c936f046d17a9d5ddd00d64a70f20c056/examples)

Comment: Sorry I did not read that as question. I've linked to a revision of the examples that should work with `v4_6` I'm not exactly sure what else is still unclear.

Comment: no worries, I updated the question and add the error I got ```error: no matching package named `cairo-rs` found``` I wonder do you know the solution to that ? @cafce25